# How to change Android SDK Platform-Tools?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, sdk, visual-studio-2017

I have two Windows 10 machines with the latest Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.18) installed. But one of the machines has a different *Android SDK Platform-Tools* version in the *Android SDK Manager*:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

One has `28.0.0` and the other one has `29.0.1`. How can I get them on the same version?

Comment: You can not just update and get latest version in both machine?

Comment: The *Android SDK Manager* doesn't offer me an update. Therefore this must come from a different installer (Visual Studio Installer?). But I haven't found an option yet.

Comment: Did you change the source to google? default is microsoft.

Comment: *Repository Source* is *Microsoft (Recommended)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found a way to change the [`Android SDK Platform-Tools`](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools). You can download the versions from here:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r29.0.1-windows.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.0-windows.zip

Then go to your [`Android SDK Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows#android-sdk-location) (for me it is *C:\Users\some-user\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools*) and put the files from the archive in this directory. Make a backup first - just in case.

Don't know why you can't do this in the `Android SDK manager` (Android SDKs and Tools Version 1.2.192 (d15-9/9312139)) itself and why he doesn't offer an upgrade after initial installation of Xamarin.